# statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)

Tags: iphone

I am getting warning message in red `statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)` at the if statement.

```
 - (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
    FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];

    if ([audioPlayer pause]){
        [timer invalidate];
    } else {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(secondViewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } 
    [viewController release];
}
```

Any idea how to fix it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: So, does audioPlayer return a value?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `[audioPlayer pause]` does not return any value.

Assuming that `audioPlayer` is an instance of `MPMusicPlayerController`, try

```
if(audioPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused)
```

Comment: I am using AVAudioPlayer and i dont think AVAudioPlayer have any property playbackstate.

Comment: then you'd have to check if([audioPlayer isPlaying]) then [audioPlayer pause]